# Loop over other hosts within ansible playbook using serial

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have 80+ hosts that run my application, and I'm updating a long-existing ansible playbook to change our load balancer.  In our current load balancer setup, hosts can be added/removed from the load balancer in one ansible play by shelling out to the AWS CLI.  However, we're switching to a load balancer configured on a handful of our own hosts, and we will take hosts in and out by manipulating text files on those hosts using Ansible.  I need an inner loop over different hosts within a playbook while using Serial.

I'm having trouble structuring the playbook such that I can fan out `blockinfile` commands to hosts in group `tag_Type_edge` while deploying to the 80 `tag_Type_app` hosts with serial: 25%.

Here's what I want to be able to do:

```
---
- hosts: tag_Type_app
  serial: "25%"
  pre_tasks:

    - name: Gathering ec2 facts
      action: ec2_metadata_facts

    - name: Remove from load balancers
      debug:
        msg: "This is where I'd fan out to multiple different hosts from group tag_Type_edge to manipulate
              text files to remove the 25% of hosts from tag_Type_app from the load balancer"

  tasks:
    - name: Do a bunch of work to upgrade the app on the tag_Type_app machines while out of the load balancer
      debug:
        msg: "deploy new code, restart service"


  post_tasks:
    - name: Put back in load balancer
        debug:
          msg: "This is where I'd fan out to multiple different hosts from group tag_Type_edge to manipulate
                 text files to *add* the 25% of hosts from tag_Type_app back into the load balancer"
```

How can I structure this to allow for the inner loop over `tag_Type_edge` while using serial: 25% on all the `tag_Type_app` boxes?

Comment: Currently solving this by shelling out to a separate ansible playbook, but that has to be straight evil

Answer (score 0):

If I may say so, yuk.

On the ACA project, each host had a file called `/etc/ansible/facts.d/load_balancer_state.fact`.  That was just an INI file that set `lb_state` to `enabled`, `disabled`, or `stopped`.

We then ran the `setup` module (or `gather_facts: yes`), to get the state of each host, and ran the `template` module to create the load balancer config file.  Very clean.  Very simple.

To change a state, change the file and re-run the template module.

This was dynamic inventory.

If you have static inventory, it's even easier.  Just set `lb_state` set on each host, either in an INI file like `host1 lb_state=enabled`, or in files in the `host_vars` directory.  Change the inventory, re-run the `template` module, and (if necessary) tell the loadbalancer to reload the config file.